# Get data from server side variables in a JS variable?

Tags: c#, javascript

I want to store data in a client side variable from a server side one, is it a good practice?

I have an app which uses a web service and I dont want to expose the ip on  the source code, so it would be good if I can set a client side variable with that ip.

Now someone told me that for example getting values from the Session and storing them in a JS variable could be known as a "bad thing", as it represents an XSS Hole and I dont want my website to be marked as a "unsafe" one.

The reason I want to store the value on a client side variable is so that I can use JQUERY - AJAX so that the client does not have to re load the page for every request.

Can you help me out?

Comment: Anything in the client can be accessed by the user, using the Javascript console. So if you don't want to expose the IP, it needs to be in a server variable.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inherently wrong with saving server side data on the client side.

Here's an easy way, for PHP:

```
<script>var someValue = "<?php echo $some_value; ?>";</script>
```

This saves a PHP value in the `someValue` JavaScript variable.

For more complicated data structures, here's a nice way to convert between the two languages:

```
<script>var someValue = JSON.decode("<?php echo json_encode($some_value); ?>");</script>
```

This only becomes a bad idea when the data you want to save client side is sensitive. There's no way to tell what your intentions are, so you have to use your best judgment.

Answer (score 0):

**Code Generating in JS**

```
<script >
<%= SomeMethodFromCodeBehind() %> //JS goes here.
</script >
```

- Pros: You get access to everything you want on the server.
- Cons: You are writing JS using C# and C# string methods aren't exactly templating engine.
- You will think you have access to Session, but only at code gen time!
- If you mix user input into the results, then this is "JavaScript Injection", which get's lumped in with XSS.

**Code Generating Just the Data**

```
<script >
var myNumber =  parseInt(<%= Convert.ToInt32(Session["TheNumber"]) %>,10);
var id = '<% TextBox.ClientID %>';
</script >
```

The above just generates the data, not all the code, so it's easier to see what is potential user input (maybe the Session part) and then force it to a suitable datatype, or do some JS escaping on the strings.

In my experience, I've only needed to ever do this for ClientIDs and sometimes properties of controls that don't have a clientside API.

**Calling Services**

If you don't code generate function that returns 42, maybe you can leave the function on the server and just have the JS gather the parameters.  For one, calling a webservice isn't going to be subject to XSS-- the user would have to attack the parameters of the webservice, where as in code generation, the user can do all sorts of attacks if only he can figure out how to get his code output (esp on someone elses browser). So now you get to create a JS friendly web API. Here are some things that can go wrong:

```
<script >
//Things that used to be somewhat secret are potentially public now.
PageMethods.GetSesion("Blah",onSuccess); 

//Wow, something that used to be hard for the user to tamper with is now convenient to 
//tamper with. Now Session is ALL user input (and hence evil)
PageMethods.SetSession("Blah",42); 

//Okay, now the user has the ability to read your secrets, conveniently
PageMethods.Encrypt("Blah", onSuccess); 
PageMethods.Decrypt("Blah", onSuccess); 
if(password=="xyzzy")
{
   PageMethods.ShipTheGoods(address,goods); //User can call this directly.
}
</script >
```

(I'm not promoting PageMethods, but they sure are shorter for sample code than the alternatives)

The above sort of code is another common issue when you write JS code when you're used to writing server side code. One book called this overly granular APIs and attacks on control of flow (that if statement that doesn't really protect ShipTheGoods from being called without a password)

Anyhow, in a JS page, the way to track state (i.e. Session) is just a variable, "`var customerInFocus = 'joe'`). You can use code generation to output a value-- then when you are ready to save, send it back to the server in a pagemethod (or web service) call and treat all of those parameters as user input that has possibly, probably been tampered with along the way.